# How to detect keyup and keydown event in service

Tags: android, android-windowmanager, onbackpressed

I have a CustomView which extends `LinearLayout` , I am adding it to screen using `WindowManager.addView()` method to detect key event in my service with following layout param flags

```
  LinearLayout mLinear = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext()) {
        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
            super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
            Log.i(TAG, "event");

            int action = event.getAction();
            int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
            switch (keyCode) {

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
                    Log.i("Key", "VolumeUp");

                    return true;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
                   Log.i("Key", "VolumeDown");
                    return true;

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    Log.d(TAG, " " + "KEYCODE_BACK");

                    return false;

                default:
                    return true;
            }

        }

    };

    mView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.volume_service_layout, mLinear);
    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);


    if (mView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        flag =  WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING ;


    //params
    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            100,
            100,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL;
    wm.addView(mView, params);

}
```

`dispatchKeyEvent()` is override in `customview` class,but after adding it to windows back press `Button` not working.When I am adding `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` flag backpress button working fine,I am unable to detect keyup and keydown event.

I want to detect keyup or keydown event in service class.
Please suggest any solution for this problem.

Comment: Where you have to wrote your code, I mean in Activity or Fragment?

Comment: I used this code in service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android doesn't document APIs on interacting with `volume buttons` in that case. So I think.Its not possible

Answer (score 1):

I guess you achieve this, by using with [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

**Try this,**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"...>
    //code, like activities, etc

    <receiver android:name="com.example.test.VolumeBroadcast" >
        <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
</application>
```

Example of a receiver:

```
  public class VolumeBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver{

      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           //check the intent something like:
           if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
              KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
              if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY == event.getKeyCode()) {
                 // Handle key press.
              }
           }
      }
  }
```

The way you register is like that:

```
 AudioManager am = mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
// Start listening for button presses
am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver); 
// Stop listening for button presses
am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver);
```

[Audio Playback](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html)

Comment: i am unable to detect key event,when i am using WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE

Comment: Wait, I will updating my answer and I will add here my whole code. So, you can better understand.

Comment: I tried your code,but still not working backpress button method

Comment: Please check I have updated my answer. You have to detect onbackpress key event by using broadcast receiver, while user will bress back button then broadcast will call and at the other end you have to receive it's event

Comment: I already tried this solution,When i am using your solution , unable to detect keyup or keydown event.

Answer (score -1):

To detect volume key press from service try `AccessibilityService` and override `onkeyEvent()`
then you do rest of the computation within the overridden event